# Wrong display of user names in ActiveAdmin forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I created a `FreeMeal` tab in my DB; this tab has a foreign key on the `User` tab. When I use the form in Active Admin to create a new entry of FreeMeal, I get a list of all my users for the user input; but users aren't displayed the right way, like so:

[image: FreeMeal form in ActiveAdmin]

edit: the form is automatically populated as I have the foreign key on users. I simply have the following code for this form in `app/admin/free_meals.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register FreeMeal do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "FreeMeal" do
      f.input :user
      f.input :reason
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

I would like to have this list with my users' `id`, `first_name` and `last_name`.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Could you post the code you're currently using to populate that field please?

Comment: @SRack I edited my post to answer your question

Comment: You can do like this `f.input :user, :as => :select, :collection => User.all.map{|u| ["#{u.first_name} #{u.last_name}", u.id]}`

Comment: it does the job perfectly ! thank you @MayurShah

Comment: You're Welcome !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
f.input :user, as: :select, collection: User.all.map{ |u| ["#{u.id}, #{u.first_name} #{u.last_name}", u.id]}, multiple: false
```